# How to use iMac 2009 21.5" as external display for MacBook Pro 2016

Tags: hdmi, imac, macbook-pro-retina, mini-displayport

Does anyone know how to use the monitor of an iMac 2009 21.5" with a MacBook Pro 2016?

I'm using an HDMI cable between my iMac 21.5 2009 and Macbook Pro 2016 (new one):

> Macbook Pro → Mini DisplayPort (Adaptor USB-C to USB-C, HDMI, USB) → HDMI → Adaptor Mini DisplayPort → iMac

Comment: At the moment I don't have that cable, otherwise I would have used it. The problem is that I connected them, but I can't use iMac's monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592), only the 27" versions of the Late 2009 iMac can be used as external displays.

You are out of luck with your machine; it does not support *Target Display Mode*.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/message/22897896#22897896

Comment: Hm, skimming through that thread, are you saying that you think it should be possible? Apparently it may have worked with older "true" Mini DisplayPort source devices, but none of the newer.

Comment: I thought so, but unfortunately it's not possible, even though someone claims the opposite.